scikit-learn upgrade - how to fix breaking change?
i've inherated a solution that runs in databricks runtime 7.3, and it is using scikit-learn 0.21.
Databricks runtime must be upgraded, and so existing scikit-learn version is not compatible with python version in newer databricks runtimes.
I tried to update scikit-learn version, but now the solution fails with with following messages:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree'
Code section where it fails:
bt = pickle.load(open('/dbfs/mnt/storage/Numpy/' + area + '.bt', 'rb'))

in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145652/no-module-named-sklearn-neighbors-base i read that the modules have changed name to include '_'. But i dont se that this is the case here. Is pickle invoking it?
No previous experiene with scikit, pickle and so on. What do i need to do to get the ball tree working?
Other libraries installed on the cluster/runtime:

azure-storage-blob==2.0.1 PyPI
geopy==1.23.0 PyPI
haversine PyPI
pyproj==3.7.0 PyPI
scipy PyPI
vincenty PyPI
applicationinsights PyPI
cryptography==2.9 PyPI
numpy==1.26.4 PyPI
pandas==1.5.3 PyPI
scikit-learn PyPI
shapely PyPI
xarray PyPI

